# How to pre-render pages using Notion API and Next.js on Github Actions?

Tags: reactjs, github, next.js, github-actions, notion-api

I am using [react-notion-x](https://github.com/NotionX/react-notion-x) and the unofficial Notion API for a Next.js project and am having lots of problems with it. Has anyone used it before and maybe encountered the error below? The error occurs when I prerender my website using `getStaticPaths` on Github Actions. Locally, it works fine 3/5 times.

Error on notion.getPage(a1c4c4eb2a8842e9a53a8d642b5da034)

```
HTTPError: Response code 403 (Forbidden)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/fakename/runner-two-one/_work/fakename-repo/fakename-repo/node_modules/.pnpm/got@11.8.6/node_modules/got/dist/source/as-promise/index.js:118:42)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_NON_2XX_3XX_RESPONSE',
  timings: {
    start: 1684765933516,
    socket: 1684765933520,
    lookup: 1684765933522,
    connect: 1684765933529,
    secureConnect: 1684765933551,
    upload: 1684765933553,
    response: 1684765933570,
    end: 1684765933590,
    error: undefined,
    abort: undefined,
    phases: {
      wait: 4,
      dns: 2,
      tcp: 7,
      tls: 22,
      request: 2,
      firstByte: 17,
      download: 20,
      total: 74
    }
  }
}
```

Do I maybe need to add an authToken or something else? I tried to use the authToken and the activeUser like it is described here: [LINK](https://github.com/NotionX/react-notion-x#private-pages)

That did not work and as far as I know, the authToken changes and I can't automatically fetch it.
Also, is there another way to fetch all pages in Notion below a specified root page? Not a Database but all pages?

Is there any other way to do this?

Thank you very much!